# How to break down a calculation so that it can be calculated in reverse.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have the following calculation, which will return a value between 0 and 7.99 Depending on the N.

$$
f(n)=8-8*exp(-0.010*n)
$$

Now I am trying to calculate what N would need to be to achieve f(n) = 5, but I am unsure how to break down the calculation in a way to do so.

My original taught was to switch the initial 8 with a 5 instead and see if it exceeds 0, but this would still require prior knowledge of n
$$ 5-8*exp(-0.010*n) $$

With that my question being, how can I break a calculation to determine what n should be to achieve a certain f(n)?

Comment: Have you used logarithms before? Can't understand  why you'd swap the 5 and 8.

Comment: To improve your understanding I recommend thinking about what happens for large $n $

Comment: @Karl never before, in the process of learning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we haveb $$5=8-8e^{-\frac{1}{100}n}$$ then we get
$$\frac{3}{8}=e^{-\frac{1}{100}n}$$
taking the logarithm on both sides we have
$$\ln\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)=-\frac{1}{100}n$$
from here we get
$$n=-100\ln\left(\frac{3}{8}\right)$$